# What are exact settings in Adobe Acrobat "Reduced Size PDF..." relative to "Optimized PDF..."?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, optimize

Does anybody know what are the exact settings whne saving a PDF document in "Reduced Size PDF..." vs. saving it in "Optimized PDF..."?

I know "Optimized PDF..." has different modes like Standard, Mobile, Low, Very Low and any custum combination of the settings.

So whne you take the save as "Reduced Size PDF..." option, which of the custom settings get optimized. I know its not equivalent to custom in PDF Optimizer because the file size comes out different.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the settings used for "Reduced Size" have never been made public by Adobe.

It is, however, a common understanding to avoid "Reduced Size" if you can use the PDF Optimizer (save as Optimized), because you have control over what happens, particularly with the discarding and cleaning up.